# Telebot. How to create a list of commands manually and unique for different users?

Tags: python, telebot

I am creating a project where I need a list of other commands for some users. I used the `set_my_commands` function, but it overwrites commands for all users.
Here is my original code in `main.py`:

```
import telebot
API_TOKEN = "<token>" 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

bot.set_my_commands(
   commands=[
      telebot.types.BotCommand('name1', 'description for name1'),
      telebot.types.BotCommand('name2', 'description for name2'),
      telebot.types.BotCommand('name3', 'description for name3')
   ]
)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

But what needs to be modified to make this happen for just one user? *Answer below.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, only one line needed to be added.

If it is necessary to rewrite commands for only **one user**, the following code can be used.

```
import telebot
API_TOKEN = "<token>" 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

bot.set_my_commands(
   commands=[
      telebot.types.BotCommand('name1', 'description for name1'),
      telebot.types.BotCommand('name2', 'description for name2'),
      telebot.types.BotCommand('name3', 'description for name3')
   ],
   scope=telebot.types.BotCommandScopeChat(chatid)
)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

In the same way, you can rewrite the list of commands by changing only the commands and the line with `scope` (see the reference(1)).

To rewrite the command list for several users, but their id code is known. I use `ChatFilter`. Example.

```
import telebot
from telebot import custom_filters
API_TOKEN = "<token>" 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(chat_id=[1570745503, -1001784204202], commands=['update'])
def update_comand(message):
    bot.set_my_commands(
        commands=[
            telebot.types.BotCommand('name1', 'description for name1'),
            telebot.types.BotCommand('name2', 'description for name2'),
            telebot.types.BotCommand('name3', 'description for name3')
        ],
        scope=telebot.types.BotCommandScopeChat(message.chat.id)
    )

bot.add_custom_filter(custom_filters.ChatFilter())
bot.infinity_polling()
```

References:

`set_my_commands`  [set_my_commands description](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmycommands)

`botcommandscope`  [description of available botcommandscope](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#botcommandscope)